# Gentelella Bootstrap theme rights

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, licensing, gentelella

**I saw this bootstrap template:** 
https://colorlib.com/polygon/gentelella/index.html

**This is the licence:** https://github.com/puikinsh/gentelella/blob/master/LICENSE.txt

Can I ask money for logging in if I customize the template?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

short answer: yes you can modify. [MIT license](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIT_License)